# Displaying the address of a string

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code:

```
char* hello = "Hello World";
std::cout << "Pointer value = " << hello << std::endl;
std::cout << "Pointer address = " << &hello << std::endl;
```

And here is the result:

```
Pointer value = Hello World
Pointer address = 0012FF74
```

When I debug to my program using OllyDbg, I see that the value of 0x0012FF74 is e.g. 0x00412374.

Is there any way I can print the actual address that `hello` points to?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you use `&hello` it prints the address of the pointer, not the address of the string. Cast the pointer to a `void*` to use the correct overload of `operator<<`.

```
std::cout << "String address = " << static_cast<void*>(hello) << std::endl;
```

Comment: @user1203803 , why do you need to cast it to a void* ?

Answer (score 13):

I don't have a compiler but probably the following works:

```
std::cout << "Pointer address = " << (void*) hello << std::endl;
```

Reason: using only hello would treat is as a string (char array), by casting it to a void pointer it will be shown as hex address.

Answer (score 4):

or so:

```
std::cout << "Pointer address = " << &hello[0] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
std::cout << "Pointer address = " << (int *)hello << std::endl;
```

Comment: please add some explanation as well if possible.

Comment: This may cause undefined behaviour if `hello` is not correctly aligned for `int`. Given that the version with `void *` works there's not any reason to use this.